# Is "Connect 4 is Excellent, Connect 3 is Great" a solved game?

Tags: mathematics, optimization, logic-grid

[Connect 4 is known to be a solved game.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solved_game)

I am introducing the **Connect 4 is Excellent, Connect 3 is Great**, variant of Connect 4.

Both players play like connect 4 and fill the grid i.e. they don't stop when 4 or more of a color is connected in a row, as contrary to classic connect 4.

When the grid is filled. For all 4 colors or more connected a player gets, he scores 3 points and for all 3 colors exactly a player gets, he scores 1 point.

Here is a example:

| X | O | X | X | O | O | X |
| X | O | O | X | O | X | X |
| X | X | O | O | O | O | X |
| O | X | O | X | X | X | O |
| X | O | O | O | X | O | X |
| X | O | X | O | O | X | O |

In this example,

X scores $0\times 3 $ points (it doesn't have any 4 connected X) + $5\times 1$ points = $5$ points
O scores $3\times 3$ points (it has one vertical 4 connected, one horizontal and one diagonal) + $5\times 1$ points = $14$ points

This is a large victory for O!

**The puzzle asks: is Connect 4 is Excellent, Connect 3 is Great a solved game? Can you prove your answer?**

Comment: I am a bit disappointed that a connect 5 or connect 6 doesn't bring 5 or 8 points...

Comment: @Evargalo haha, I did think about it. My plan is to wait for an answer for this puzzle then give a more advance one where connect 2 gives 1 point, connect 3, 2 points, connect 4, 4 points, connect 5, 6 points, connect 6, 10 points, connect 7 is infinite number of points but should probably not happen :)

Comment: What do you mean "solved?" Do you mean, can the players optimize their play?

Comment: Before I put too much thought into this, do you know if this has an answer? Or is it an open question?

Comment: @BobaFit, I mean exactly what is said in the Wikipedia page I gave in my puzzle. Either ultra weak, weak and strong levels would be an accepted proof that it is a solved game :)

Comment: @Trenin, it is an open question! We invented this game with my girlfriend because we found that the classical connect 4 was too boring and still wanted to make an interesting use of the boardgame we have. If someone says this new variant is also a solved game, I might tell her that we either need to complexify our rules or give up making the boardgame interesting!

Comment: OK.  It took a long time on a computer to solve the basic problem, so this will likely take a similar effort and not be possible to explain on this forum easily.  However, I could be wrong and it might be that this added rule actually makes it simpler to solve.

Comment: BTW - just because a game is solved theoretically, doesn't mean you or your girlfriend need to find a different game. The optimal play might still be very complex difficult to determine in every situation.

Comment: Here is an interesting resource if you want to try this yourself. https://github.com/lhorrell99/connect-4-solver

Comment: @Trenin, you are totally right for your BTW ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one idea to consider.  In classic connect 4, you can always win if you go first.  In this version of connect 4, the

> second player can always force a tie.

The strategy is simple.

> Drop a piece in the same slot that player 1 drops a piece.

This results in a board where

> player 1 owns all the places in the first row, player 2 owns the entire second row, player 1 the third, etc.

While this strategy trivializes the game, there might be a more complex strategy that

> guarantees a win for player 2

Comment: Great ;) You might be super interested by the final version! https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/118699/51928